# How to sum (by year) the substraction of two columns showing a running sum of it in the same record

Tags: sql, oracle

With data like this

```sql
    --  Sample data:
    CREATE TABLE IN_OUT_TABLE (DATE_OF Date, INPUT_CASES Number(3), OUTPUT_CASES Number(3));
    --
    Insert Into IN_OUT_TABLE Values(To_Date('01-AUG-2019', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), 2, 1);
    Insert Into IN_OUT_TABLE Values(To_Date('01-SEP-2019', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), 3, 1);
    Insert Into IN_OUT_TABLE Values(To_Date('01-MAY-2020', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), 3, 3);
    Insert Into IN_OUT_TABLE Values(To_Date('01-MAR-2020', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), 7, 2);
    Insert Into IN_OUT_TABLE Values(To_Date('01-APR-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), 3, 1);
    Insert Into IN_OUT_TABLE Values(To_Date('01-JUL-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), 4, 2);
```

Need to select the sum of the diferencies between input and output cases
(INPUT_CASES - OUTPUT_CASES) grouped by year of the DATE_OF.
The result should be shown as PERIOD for a particular year.  Beside,  there should be a CUMULATIVE column showing running sum of PERIOD values.
So,
PERIOD = INPUT_CASES - OUTPUT_CASES  - this should be summed by year
CUMULATIVE = running sum of PERIOD - year by year (ordered by year)

Having that in mind is it posible to construct a select command something like this

```sql
    SELECT DATE, PERIOD, SUM(PERIOD) OVER(ORDER BY DATE) 
    FROM (  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE) as DATE, SUM(PERIOD) as PERIOD
            FROM IN_OUT_TABLE
            GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE))
```

... ... and get the expected result?

Expected result would be:

```sql
    --  YEAR       PERIOD     CUMULATIVE   
    --  ----  -----------  -------------
    --  2019            3              3
    --  2020            5              8
    --  2021            4             12
```

Thanks, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this maybe the answer that you are looking for?...

```
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select To_Date('01-AUG-2019', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "DT", 2 "INP", 1 "OUTP" From DUAL UNION ALL
            Select To_Date('01-SEP-2019', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "DT", 3 "INP", 1 "OUTP" From DUAL UNION ALL
            Select To_Date('01-MAY-2020', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "DT", 3 "INP", 3 "OUTP" From DUAL UNION ALL
            Select To_Date('01-MAR-2020', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "DT", 7 "INP", 2 "OUTP" From DUAL UNION ALL
            Select To_Date('01-APR-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "DT", 3 "INP", 1 "OUTP" From DUAL UNION ALL
            Select To_Date('01-JUL-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy') "DT", 4 "INP", 2 "OUTP" From DUAL 
        )
SELECT
    YR,
    PERIOD,
    Sum(PERIOD) OVER(Order By YR ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "CUMUL"
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT) "YR",
          Sum(INP- OUTP) OVER(Partition By EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT) Order By EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT)) "PERIOD"
        FROM
          tbl
        ORDER BY
          EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT)
    )
--
--  R e s u l t
--  
--          YR     PERIOD      CUMUL
--  ---------- ---------- ----------
--        2019          3          3 
--        2020          5          8 
--        2021          4         12
```

Comment: In the inner query you can use analytic function (  Sum(INP- OUTP) OVER(Partition....) ) to calculate the yearly sums of the difference between input and output, and in the outer query you can use window clause (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) in analytic function to get the result you asked for.

Comment: Your inner query gives the same result as one in the answer. Just wanted to introduce analytic function as an alternative. The outer query and windowing clause is something that you need here. Regards...  https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions

Comment: In the subquery, you use an analytic function and then DISTINCT in the SELECT clause, where you should use an aggregate function instead. This will destroy execution time. You do need an analytic function on the result of aggregation by year.

Comment: @mathguy: Thanks, You are absolutely right about execution time. Didn't pay attention to that, my fault. Just wanted to introduce use of analytic function with and without the windowing clause. Though said that the inner query could stay as it is in the question, the fact you warn me about stays. Thnaks again..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
with
  tbl (date_, input, output) as (
    select date '2019-08-01', 2, 1 from dual union all
    select date '2019-09-01', 3, 1 from dual union all
    select date '2020-05-01', 3, 3 from dual union all
    select date '2020-03-01', 7, 2 from dual union all
    select date '2021-04-01', 3, 1 from dual union all
    select date '2021-07-01', 4, 2 from dual 
  )
select extract(year from trunc(date_, 'year'))  as year_,
       nvl(sum(input), 0) - nvl(sum(output), 0) as period,
       sum(nvl(sum(input), 0) - nvl(sum(output), 0))
         over (order by trunc(date_, 'year'))   as cumulative
from   tbl
group  by trunc(date_, 'year')
order  by year_
;

     YEAR_     PERIOD CUMULATIVE
---------- ---------- ----------
      2019          3          3
      2020          5          8
      2021          4         12
```

The `with` clause is for testing purposes only, it is not part of the query. To test the query on your actual data, remove the `with` clause, and use your actual table and column names (I used `tbl` for the table, and `date_`, `input` and `output` for the columns - note that `date` is a reserved keyword, which should not be used as column name).

In the query I truncate each date to the beginning of the year, and I group by the result. If there is an index on the `date_` column, this may be more efficient than extracting the year with the `extract` function. (Worth trying both ways on your actual data.) In any case, you should need only one pass over the base data.

I wrapped the sums of `input` and `output` within `nvl(..., 0)` - that way if in a year all inputs (or all outputs) are `null`, the sum will be treated as 0, instead of messing up the difference (the `period` result).